# elasticsearch performance will it be slow if we hit a index too frequently

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

First I had one API which was using elasticsearch index(For example let's keep the index name as index_one). But now I have one more API which wants whatever data present in index_one and additional data. 
So I added more fields to the existing index index_one since my second API requires additional data.

But now elasticsearch response looks slower. I know that if elasticsearch doc size gets bigger then performance will get affected. But apart from this, is there any other reason that causes slow elasticsearch response?

So my doubt is since two APIs are using the same index whether it will cause slow elasticsearch response?

Comment: that's unlikely. When you say that elasticsearch response looks slower, do you mean responses to the first API?

Comment: @glenacota In both APIs ES response looks slower.

Answer (score 3):

It could be many things, and impossible to give you a good answer without knowing too many details about your implementation. But I would start with ( with a lot of assumptions - including assumption that you are dealing with reasonably bigger index )

- Check /_cat/thread_pools and look at `search queue.` Do you see requests queued? In that case, it could be volume, and you may need more replicas
- Do a query with no source to see if it's just source parsing in the application is the thing which slows it down.